# how to call a list of prolog queries questionning a logic programm?

Tags: swi-prolog

I would like to call automatically a list of queries in a file:

```
file queries.txt
consult(uwr).
submit_emit_timers(1).
activate_game(1,detroit,3,berlin,1).
submit_emit_timers(1).
start_game(1).
sleep(5).
submit_emit_timers(1).
sleep(5).
stop_game(1).
submit_emit_timers(1).
sleep(5).
start_timeout(1,blue).
start_game(1).
stop_game(1).
timepenalty_player(5,blue).
start_game(1).
stop_game(1).
start_penalty(blue).
start_game(1).
etc....
leave.
```

I would like to know how to call this automatically with SWI-prolog.
`uwr.pl` is the logic file.

I am doing it with line command but this is heavy going (I start swipl in a terminal, then all the queries above by manual clicking). calling a queries file will help for debugging.
later, I will pass these queries via sockets.
(sorry for my poor editing here; I have still to learn in order to make looking like a list).

Comment: New idea. I am doing for now: start swipl, "consult(uwr)." then "testing." where I created a rule in uwr.pl "testing :- with all the command above." Seems to be fine for now for debugging (= a single uwr.pl file and 2 commands in swipl). If somebody has a better idea, this is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Run `swipl` with the `-s` options.

Start SWI-Prolog with the command `swipl -s uwr.pl -s testing.pl`.

Then you can call:

```
?- testing.
```

After you edit your files, you can reload your files by running `make.`.

```
?- make.
```

If your files have no errors, you can also do this to reload before running the commands:

```
?- make, testing.
```

If `make` doesn't work, you can restart SWI-Prolog:
If you are running swipl in a terminal on Linux, you can usually Ctrl+D, Ctrl+P, Ctrl+J.

If you can't press Ctrl+P, Up Arrow usually also works.

If you can't press Ctrl+J, Enter usually also works.

If your SWI-Prolog have readline, you can use Ctrl+P in SWI-Prolog as well.